# Move mail with programmatically created rule

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I'm trying to create a custom mail rule in Outlook, to move mail from a specific email address to a specific folder.

```cs
public partial class Ribbon1{

    private Outlook.Folders allFolders;

    private void Ribbon1_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
    {
        Outlook.MAPIFolder inbox = ThisAddIn.app.ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
        Outlook.MAPIFolder mainFolder = inbox.Parent;
        allFolders = mainFolder.Folders;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        Outlook.Rules rules = null;

        try
        {
            rules = ThisAddIn.app.Session.DefaultStore.GetRules(); //Gets list of outlook rules
        }
        catch
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Could not obtain rules collection.");
            return;
        }

        string ruleName = "TestRule";

        Outlook.Rule rule = rules.Create(ruleName, Outlook.OlRuleType.olRuleReceive);
        rule.Name = ruleName;

        rule.Conditions.From.Recipients.Add("test12345@hotmail.com");
        rule.Conditions.From.Enabled = true;

        Outlook.MAPIFolder ruleFolder = allFolders["test1"];
        rule.Actions.MoveToFolder.Folder = ruleFolder;
        rule.Actions.MoveToFolder.Enabled = true;

        rule.Enabled = true;

        //Save rules
        try
        {
            rules.Save(true);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

I have a button that when clicked a custom rule is added to Outlook. I checked on Outlook rule window. When I send myself at "test12345@hotmail.com", it does not move mail to "test1" folder.

When I create it manually it works correctly.

Comment: Does the rule work correct;y if you create it manually?

Comment: Yes, i create it manually and it works correctly.

Comment: Have you tried to compare the good and the bad rules? You can do that in OutlookSpy - click Store button, Functions tab, select GetRules, click Call, go to the IEnumVarint tab, double click on the rules.

Comment: In case of an Exchange store, you can also to to the Inbox folder, click IMAPIFolder button, go to the PR_RULES_TABLE tab, double click n the PR_RULE_ACTIONS and PR_RULE_CONDITION properties for the two rules.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the sequence of actions/calls looks good. But recipients should be resolved against the address book. And I'd recommend starting from breaking down lines of codes with multiple dots. Thus, all underlying COM objects will be released. Moreover, it can lead to the rights results because each time calling the same property you may get a new object instance. For example:

```
rule.Conditions.From.Enabled = true;
```

The [Conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.rule.conditions) property of the `Rule` class returns a `RuleConditions` collection object that represents all the available rule conditions for the rule. So, it should be released instantly. Use [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/843807e2) to release an Outlook object when you have finished using it. Then set a variable to Nothing in Visual Basic (null in C#) to release the reference to the object. Read more about that in the [Systematically Releasing Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/bb623945(v=office.12)) article.

```
Sub CreateRule()  
  Dim colRules As Outlook.Rules 
  Dim oRule As Outlook.Rule  
  Dim colRuleActions As Outlook.RuleActions  
  Dim oMoveRuleAction As Outlook.MoveOrCopyRuleAction  
  Dim oFromCondition As Outlook.ToOrFromRuleCondition  
  Dim oExceptSubject As Outlook.TextRuleCondition  
  Dim oInbox As Outlook.Folder  
  Dim oMoveTarget As Outlook.Folder 

  'Specify target folder for rule move action  
  Set oInbox = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)  
  'Assume that target folder already exists  
  Set oMoveTarget = oInbox.Folders("Dan")  

  'Get Rules from Session.DefaultStore object 
  Set colRules = Application.Session.DefaultStore.GetRules()  

  'Create the rule by adding a Receive Rule to Rules collection 
  Set oRule = colRules.Create("Dan's rule", olRuleReceive) 

  'Specify the condition in a ToOrFromRuleCondition object  
  'Condition is if the message is sent by "DanWilson"  
  Set oFromCondition = oRule.Conditions.From  
  With oFromCondition  
      .Enabled = True  
      .Recipients.Add ("DanWilson")  
      .Recipients.ResolveAll  
  End With 

  'Specify the action in a MoveOrCopyRuleAction object  
  'Action is to move the message to the target folder  
  Set oMoveRuleAction = oRule.Actions.MoveToFolder  
  With oMoveRuleAction 
    .Enabled = True  
    .Folder = oMoveTarget  
  End With  

  'Specify the exception condition for the subject in a TextRuleCondition object  
  'Exception condition is if the subject contains "fun" or "chat"  
   Set oExceptSubject = oRule.Exceptions.Subject 

   With oExceptSubject  
     .Enabled = True  
     .Text = Array("fun", "chat")  
   End With  

   'Update the server and display progress dialog  
   colRules.Save  
 End Sub
```

Also, I'd recommend checking the sample code which works correctly for others:

- [How to create custom Outlook rules and execute them programmatically: C# example](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/12/13/create-outlook-rules-programmatically/)